# Symfony2 Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to ... must be an instance of ... integer given, called in

Tags: symfony, set

I have problems in coding. when I send you the form, and save to the database, a message like this:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to ITTBundle\Entity\Student::setFormClass() must be an instance of ITTBundle\Entity\FormClass, integer given, called in C:\Users\Rivan\Documents\DigitalSchoolBase\Symfony2\src\ITTBundle\Controller\ConfigureController.php on line 601 and defined in C:\Users\Rivan\Documents\DigitalSchoolBase\Symfony2\src\ITTBundle\Entity\Student.php on line 901
```

Here is my code :

```
  $findclass = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('ITTBundle:FormClass')
    ->findOneBy(array('class_level' => $classlevel->getId(), 'letter' => $letter, 'class_major' => $classmajor->getId()));

    //print_r($findclass->getId()); exit;
    if( empty($error_message) )    
    {
      If ($findclass)
      {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $students->setFormClass($findclass->getId());
        $em->persist($students);
        $em->flush();
      }

    }
```

I wonder with which this issue. The coding of my other, the way this works fine, but I was confused when this method can not be used in this my coding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the example you provided, I assume this is line `601`, which is triggering the fatal error:

```
$students->setFormClass($findclass->getId());
```

I assume that the method call `\ITTBundle\Entity\Student::setFormClass()` requires an object of type `\ITTBundle\Entity\FormClass`. You are returning a entity from the database, but then you but then you are explicitly passing the object's id - which is an integer - instead of the `FormClass` object itself.

Try this:

```
$students->setFormClass($findclass);
```

We can only tell for sure if you show us the method signature of `\ITTBundle\Entity\Student::setFormClass()`, but that's my semi-educated assumption. Given the method call itself is throwing an error for an unexpected argument type, I assume the method argument is typed so I guess is that it may look like this:

```php
public function setFormClass(\ITTBundle\Entity\FormClass $formClass)
{
    $this->formClass = $formClass;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: No problem :) glad to help. Don't know who downvoted you, seems a tad unreasonable given your question seemed fine to me.

Comment: It's fine! I understood your question.